# Operation 'GetImagesRequest' of contract 'IRetrieveInformation' specifies multiple request body parameters to be serialized without any wrapper el

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, web-services, wcf

I am trying to write a RESTful WCF Service that is callable by a jQuery AJAX function. I was having problems figuring out the correct URL to use, so I wrote the code to call back to the code behind, and have the code behind call to the service to make sure the service was working correctly. So here's the problem. When the code behind made a call to one service function I get this error about another:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   System.ServiceModel.Web.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Operation 'GetImagesRequest' of contract
>   'IRetrieveInformation' specifies multiple request body parameters to
>   be serialized without any wrapper elements. At most one body parameter
>   can be serialized without wrapper elements. Either remove the extra
>   body parameters or set the BodyStyle property on the
>   WebGetAttribute/WebInvokeAttribute to Wrapped.

I have read so many posts that said to make the  `BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped`. Easy enough fix, except that my method was already decorated with that. I tried to comment out the code in the service because that was not the function I was testing anyway, but I always get the same error. Please someone, anyone, HELP!!!

SERVICE INTERFACE:

```
namespace DigitalSignage.Services
{
    //[ServiceContract(ConfigurationName = "Data.GetData")]
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IRetrieveInformation
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "GetImagesRequest?slideshow={slideshow}")]
        string GetImagesRequest(DisplaySlideShow slideshow);

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        string GetNewsRequest();

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        string GetCalendarRequest(DisplayLocation location);

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        string GetLayoutRequest(DisplayLocation location);
    }
}
```

SERVICE IMPLEMENTATION:

```
    namespace DigitalSignage.Services
{
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class RetrieveInformation : IRetrieveInformation
    {
        public string GetImagesRequest(DisplaySlideShow slideshow)
        {
            RetrieveImages ri = new RetrieveImages();
            return ri.GetImageLocation(slideshow);
        }

        public string GetNewsRequest()
        {
            RetrieveNews rn = new RetrieveNews();
            return rn.GetSigmaNews();
        }

        public string GetCalendarRequest(DisplayLocation location)
        {
            RetrieveCalendar rc = new RetrieveCalendar();
            return rc.GetCalendar(location);
        }

        public string GetLayoutRequest(DisplayLocation location)
        {
            RetrieveLayout rl = new RetrieveLayout();
            return rl.GetLayout(location);
        }
    }
}
```

SERVICE WEB CONFIG:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
  </system.web>


  <system.serviceModel>
    <!--<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />-->
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="Service.WebHttpBinding">
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <services>
      <service name="DigitalSignage.Services.RetrieveInformation" behaviorConfiguration="Service.ServiceBehaviors">
        <endpoint address=""
                  contract="DigitalSignage.Services.IRetrieveInformation"
                  binding="webHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="Service.WebHttpBinding"
                  behaviorConfiguration="Service.EndpointBehaviors"/>
        <!--  Enable AJAX Calls -->
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <!--  Enable AJAX Calls -->
        <behavior name="ServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
          <enableWebScript />
        </behavior>

        <behavior name="Service.EndpointBehaviors">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Service.ServiceBehaviors">
          <serviceSecurityAudit auditLogLocation="Application" suppressAuditFailure="true"
            serviceAuthorizationAuditLevel="Failure" messageAuthenticationAuditLevel="SuccessOrFailure" />
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>

        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>


  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

CODE BEHIND CALL:

```
 [WebMethod]
    public static string GetCalendar(string city, string building, string room)
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer jsonSeralizer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        try
        {
            string calendarString = ri.GetCalendarRequest(city, building, room).ToString();
            return jsonSeralizer.Serialize(calendarString);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public static string GetSigmaNews()
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer jsonSeralizer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        string news = ri.GetNewsRequest();
        return jsonSeralizer.Serialize(news);
    }


    [WebMethod]
    public static string GetImages(string folderName, string city, string building, string room)
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer jsonSeralizer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string imagesList = ri.GetImagesRequest(folderName, city, building, room);
        return jsonSeralizer.Serialize(imagesList);
    }
```

jQuery AJAX CALL (one sample):

```
function getCalendar() {
    var dataString = '{"city":' + $('#hdnCity').val() + '", "building":"' + $('#hdnBuilding').val() + '", "room":"' + $('#hdnRoom').val() + '"}';
    $.ajax({
        type: "Post",
        url: "Layout2.aspx/GetCalendar",
        data: dataString,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function complete(result, jqXHR, status) {
            var calendar = JSON.parse(result.d);
            $('#calendar').append(calendar);
        },
        error: function (result, jqXHR, status) {
            alert("getCalendar failed because: " + JSON.parse(result.responseText).Message);
        }
    });
}
```

FRONT END WEB CONFIG:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" executionTimeout="90" maxRequestLength="11264" />
  </system.web>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs"
        type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701"/>
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb"
        type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+"/>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <!--<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />-->
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="Service.WebHttpBinding">
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <client>

      <!--<service name="DigitalSignage.Services.IRetrieveInformation.svc" behaviorConfiguration="Service.ServiceBehaviors">-->
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:50675/DigitalSignage.Services.IRetrieveInformation"
                  contract="DigitalSignage.Services.IRetrieveInformation"
                  binding="webHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="Service.WebHttpBinding"
                  behaviorConfiguration="Service.EndpointBehaviors"/>
      <!--</service>-->
    </client>

    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Service.EndpointBehaviors">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Service.ServiceBehaviors">
          <serviceSecurityAudit auditLogLocation="Application" suppressAuditFailure="true"
            serviceAuthorizationAuditLevel="Failure" messageAuthenticationAuditLevel="SuccessOrFailure" />
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>

        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Have you tried to use templateuri like this:
UriTemplate = "GetImagesRequest/{slideshow}"

Comment: I have this on the end of the GetImagesRequest
UriTemplate = "GetImagesRequest?slideshow={slideshow}"

Is the question mark not the correct syntax?

Comment: I tried it as you suggested, and I still get the same error.